# Why is Phplist responding with 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: apache-2.4, php5, 500-error, phplist

I just did a fresh install of phplist, but when I attempt to access it in my browser, I get an empty page with status code: `"500 Internal Server Error"`

I'm running CentOS 7 and Phplist is being served on Apache v2.4.6 with Php v5.6.33.

I can see the query in my apache's `access_log`, but there are no entries in the error_log. The vhost config file and `.htaccess` files all seem ok.

Please help me debug why phplist is giving me a 500 error after a fresh install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through the phplist code for many hours, I fixed this by installing libsodium on my server.

First of all, I found that--by default--phplist will *suppress* errors from being written to logs. This is not documented anywhere, so I left a note on their documentation page asking them to document how to re-enable error messages to be written to log files (link below)

So to prevent phplist from suppressing errors from your log files, you'll want to change `error_reporting(0)` to `error_reporting(1)`  in `'lists/admin/init.php'` and `'lists/admin/index.php'` as [I described here](https://discuss.phplist.org/t/troubleshooting-techniques-manual-chapter-feedback-and-discussion/234/2).

Then I was able to see the following exception being thrown in the apache `error_log` file by the `'lists/admin/inc/random_compat/random.php'` file, which is part of the `random_compat` library that's included with phplist.

```
[Thu Aug 23 00:06:29.560157 2018] [:error] [pid 17617] [client 127.0.0.1:51262] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'There is no suitable CSPRNG installed on your system' in /var/www/html/phplist.opensourceecology.org/public_html/lists/admin/inc/random_compat/random.php:204\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/phplist.opensourceecology.org/public_html/lists/admin/defaultconfig.php(3): random_bytes(10)\n#1 /var/www/html/phplist.opensourceecology.org/public_html/lists/admin/index.php(103): require_once('/var/www/html/p...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/phplist.opensourceecology.org/public_html/lists/admin/inc/random_compat/random.php on line 204
```

The official response from the maintainers ([see issue #99 of the random_compat repo on github](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/issues/99)) is to simply add `'/dev/urandom'` to `open_basedir` in `'/etc/php.ini'`. Personally, that didn’t seem like the wisest option..

Alternatively, I decided to install libsodium. In CentOS 7, that means just installing the `'php-pecl-libsodium'` package and restarting the apache webserver.

```
yum install php-pecl-libsodium
httpd -t && service httpd restart
```

For more information on this error, please see my write-up titled [fix phplist 500 error due to random_compat](https://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2018/08/25/fix-phplist-500-error-due-to-random_compat/).

Comment: Why is the default error setting off? After an hour of digging I was able to resolve the issue in a few minutes once the errors were turned back on?

Answer (score -1):

I was suffering with this error since a few months ago, I had to install phplist old versions.

I just discovered that the new versions of php (in my case I was working with php-5.2 but centos 7 came with php-5.4) has a new parameter (ok... new for me) called "date.timezone". My "/etc/php.ini" now has:

date.timezone = "America/Guayaquil"

You can check the valid timezone names at:

http://php.net/manual/es/timezones.php

Best regards and good luck!